# TO_CHAR function logic <<Number format>>

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle and found something hard to understand. Even though i understand the functionality of TO_CHAR , i am new to concept of number format model. Please help me understand the below logic.

```
select TRIM(substr(TO_CHAR (160, '000'),1,3)) from dual;
Output -> 16

select TRIM(substr(TO_CHAR (160),1,3)) from dual;
Output -> 160
```

> For the 1st query why has the oracle returned the value 16 rather than
>   160?

Comment: Why do you trim your expression?

Comment: You need to use '999'. The `0` format specifier is used for leading/trailing zeroes. Format models are specified here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Comment: @cha No, that makes no difference

Comment: read https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/TO_CHAR-number.htm#SQLRF06130 and https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Format-Models.htm#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C__BABIGFBA and https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Format-Models.htm#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the format string with `FM`, e.g. `'FM000'`.
Without the `FM` there is a preceding space saved for a minus sign.

```
select  '|' || to_char(160,'000')   || '|'     as no_FM
       ,'|' || to_char(160,'FM000') || '|'     as with_FM

from    dual
```

---

```
+--------+---------+
| NO_FM  | WITH_FM |
+--------+---------+
| | 160| | |160|   |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: I'll be near a computer in 15 minutes

Comment: sorry, a mistake I appended erroneously a blank ('FM000 ')to the format and got ORA-01481: invalid number format model

Comment: Thanks for making me understand the concept. Took me a while to understand the extra space before the value 16. Now i understood.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. Tried this:

```
select to_char(160, '000')
      ,substr(to_char(160, '000'), 1, 3)
      ,substr('160', 1, 3)
      ,length(to_char(160, '000'))
  from dual;
```

Which gave me 160, 16 , 160, 4

The substring gives you the first 3 characters of the string. The fist character of to_char(160,'000') is a space. A place is reserved for a minus sign.
So the value of substr(to_char(160, '000'), 1, 3) is not 16 but space16.

Answer (score 0):

### if you try like this

```
select substr(TRIM(TO_CHAR (160, '000')),1,3) from dual;
```

Output -> 160

instead of this:

```
select TRIM(substr(TO_CHAR (160, '000'),1,3)) from dual;
```